# Dojo DataGrid and CsvStore

Tags: csv, datagrid, store, dojo

I'm using Dojo 1.7 and I have a problem with the `dojox/grid/DataGrid` and `dojox/data/CsvStore`. I want to create a dojo `DataGrid` that responds to text input from the user. The user would type in something that is in CSV format into the text area and the `CsvStore` would read that data and feed it to the `DataGrid` but I have a few problems and questions.

1. `CsvStore` doesn't always load on time. That is, the `_loadFinished` property isn't always true when it is time to feed it to the `DataGrid`. Do I have to use `Deferred` or something? This object has no event properties as I had hoped.
2. It seems that `DataGrid` must absolutely have to have the `structure` property declared. I'm not sure if this is true can someone please tell me? Is there a way to bypass this? Because if not this leads to my third problem.
3. If I need to declare my `DataGrid` structure/layout, I need to know the fieldnames which I need to extract from `CsvStore` since I have no idea what my data looks like. I'm not sure how to do this because I can't call the internal `_attributes` property that holds the field names. It seems to me that my best bet is using the `getAttributes(item)` method but I don't know what `item` is and according to the documentation, this valuable is required.

Thanks for all your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone interested, this is how I fixed the issue.

1. Apparently `CsvStore` and all of the Dojo stores don't use their primary method `_processData` unless called by some other widget such as the Grid so it belongs on the same thread.
2. `DataGrid` must have a structure which is bizarre. I think it should be optional
3. There was no way to retrieve those fieldnames. I had to use string manipulation (sad-face). Maybe I'm wrong, hopefully someone can tell me how.